# How to check for tag contain specific attribute or not?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to **scrape** img tags from content.but problem is some of the img containg data-src and some containg src.

i have tried following :

if(content.find('img',{'itemprop':'contentUrl'})['data-src']):

```
image=content.find('img',{'itemprop':'contentUrl'})['data-src']
```

elif(content.find('img',{'itemprop':'contentUrl'})['src']):

```
image=content.find('img',{'itemprop':'contentUrl'})['src']
```

Still it's not working i want to scrape all image url where it contain data-src or src .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try thiswith   `item.attrs` .

```
for item in content.select('img[itemprop="contentUrl"]'):
    if 'data-src' in item.attrs:
        print(item['data-src'])
    if 'src' in item.attrs:
        print(item['src'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with lambda, something like this:

```
img_l = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, "name") == "img" and "src" in tag.attrs)
images = content.find_all(img_l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector Or sytax to gather list of either attribute in img tag and then used nested .get

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<img src="mePlease.gif" alt="Yey" height="42" width="42">
<img data-src="me2.gif" alt="Yey" height="42" width="42">
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
attrs = [i.get('src', i.get('data-src', None)) for i in soup.select('img[src],img[data-src]')]
print(attrs)
```